# Unable to run Existing expo project on another system,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am not able to start expo project using expo start.
Bundler is running but when i scan the QR code in expo client nothing happens.

After ejecting project and run using android studio is also not working.
Anyone has idea how to fix that. Thanks in advance.

More details

```
{
  "name": "my-new-project",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl": "^6.1.3",
    "expo": "35.0.0",
    "expokit": "^32.0.6",
    "geofire": "^5.0.1",
    "mobx": "^5.9.0",
    "mobx-persist": "^0.4.1",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.2.2",
    "react-native-interactable": "^0.1.10",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "jest-expo": "^32.0.0"
  }
}


Run expo start
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19009
Starting Metro Bundler on port 19011.
Successfully ran `adb reverse`. Localhost URLs should work on the connected Android device.
Your native app is running at exp2d1437b4f54d456bb554e0d5e90ab6d7://XX.XX.XX.XX:19010
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
```

this what i got in terminal but app is not runing anywhere in the device.

Comment: Your question is too broad to be answered correctly. Please give more detail and be more specific on what is the problem

Comment: I ran following command and got following results
expo start
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19009
Starting Metro Bundler on port 19011.
Successfully ran `adb reverse`. Localhost URLs should work on the connected Android device.
Your native app is running at exp2d1437b4f54d456bb554e0d5e90ab6d7://XX.XX.XX.XX:19010
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.


this what i got in terminal but app is not runing anywhere in the device.